# Hide some part of node when the field_countdown timer is zero

Tags: 8, entities

I create a field with [field_countdown](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_countdown). Now I want hide some part of my node text when the timer is zero.

For this when I use this code:

```
{% set a = 'now'|date("U") %}
{% set b = node.field_timer.value|date("U") %}
{% if a < b %}
    Show
{% else %}
    Hide
{% endif %}
```

Work but not currectly. And in first page send me an error.

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
>   TypeError: DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string,
>   array given in DateTime->__construct() (line 519 of
>   vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Extension\Core.php).

In second way I create a field like my field_timer and just show secondes and after my timer show zero IF command work but in this way I add a field and it's not good.

How can I do this with other codes in Drupal 8 ?

Comment: The field Countdown module uses jQuery Countdown Timer. So I think you would need to do this client-side too.

Comment: Thanks but how?I do two way that say in question but not good and not correctly. countdown uses jQuery but {{ node.field_timer.value }} show the end of time. how can I use that for show the time finished.

Comment: Who can help me ?

Comment: The error says it all - you are passing an array instead of a string. What is the value of `node.field_timer.value`?

Comment: @Kevin 's answer says it all. With a var_dump of node.field_timer.value `{{ dump(node.field_timer.value)}}` you should be able to identify the proper key to use for the filter date `|date("U")`

Answer (score 0):

You might use twig `without` method. It will print all configured content to be rendered without the selected fields/properties.

```
{% set a = 'now'|date("U") %}
{% set b = node.field_timer.value|date("U") %}
{% if a < b %}
    {# Show #}
    {{ content }}
{% else %}
    {# Hide - print the content without the field_timer #}
    {{ content|without('field_timer') }}
{% endif %}
```

For some cacheability issues it is recommended to always print content.

Comment: Thanks but read my question and comment.I use this but worked not correctly and when go to first page I have an error.